# Прерывание таймера

Tags: windows, winapi, c, c++

Как отключить прерывание таймера на некоторое время ?

Comment: В драйвере (kernel-mode) выполнить ассемблерную команду [`cli`][1], но нужно учитывать, что потом нужно будет восстановить изначальное значение измененного флага, иначе система потеряет работоспособность.

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLI_(x86)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два способа. Первый - просто удалить таймер. А когда нужен будет снова - создать. Правильный, нормальный способ.

Способ второй - в самое начало обработчика таймера добавить код вида

```
if (mPaused) return 0;
```

и соответственно метод для постановки на паузу

```
void MakePause()
{
  mPaused = true;
}
```

аналогичный метод, для снятия с паузы думаю напишите.

И третий способ. Если известно точное время, на которое нужно отключить таймер. Для этого текущий таймер удаляется, создается новый с нужным периодом. В его обработчике восстанавливаете старый таймер, а этот удаляете.

Comment: Я имел ввиду прерывание таймера Windows, тоесть процесорное время отдается программе, которая остановила таймер, а все остальные программы ждут, пока она закончит роботу. Или что-то типа очень высокого приоритета , которая не будет разрешать другим программам испольнение.

Comment: Ну тогда Вы очень плохо сформулировали вопрос. Вы хотите вмешаться в работу системного планировщика?
Самый надежный способ - перейти на старые версии виндовс с корпоративной многозадачностью. Там так можно.

В современных системах такое можно сделать, но придется опуститься на уровень ядра.

А какую задачу решаем, что понадобилось сделать такое?

Comment: нужно посчитать точное время работы алгоритмов и при запуске программы вряме постоянно прыгает. Решил, что нужно или увеличить приоритет программе так, чтобы всё простаивало, кроме запущеной задачи, или же остановить прерывание таймера, чтобы планировщик не смог переключатся между процесами.

Comment: а какой смысл в "точном времени", если это будет исполнятся на живой системе? Либо нужный код запускайте много раз, а потом усредняйте, либо пользуйтесь профилировщиками.

Comment: Соглашусь с @KoVadim. Используйте правильные методики измерения (с учетом многопоточности, возможности гибернации и пр.) и проводите серию измерений. Все равно абсолютно точное значение получить нельзя.